# Development threshold of a blowfly species differ depending on situation?

Tags: entomology, development, temperature

Within a species, does the lower development temperature threshold remain the same in all situations (also known as the development zero temperature)? For example, would the temperature threshold be the same for larvae grown on small carcasses compared to large carcasses? e.g. mouse carcass compared to human/pig carcass.

Comment: Are you talking about minimum developmental time when you write "lower development threshold"? To me, it is unclear what the threshold is referring to.

Comment: @fileunderwater I am referring to the lower development threshold, t, expressed in the equation D(T-t) = k, and also known as the development zero temperature.